# Como faço meu form funcionar com reCAPTCHA?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net

Estou salvando os dados por Ajax, porem meu reCaptcha não esta funcionando corretamente, o formulario é enviado mesmo sem apertar dentro do Captcha.

Meu Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  [CaptchaValidator(PrivateKey= "secretKey", ErrorMessage="Captcha 
    Invalido", RequiredMessage ="Campo Obrigatorio")]

  public ActionResult SalvarItens(string titulo, string video_url, string 
     thumb, bool captchaValid) 
    {
         var item = new Dados_Video()
            {
                Thumb = thumb,
                Titulo = titulo,
                UrlVideo = video_url
            };

            db.Dados_Video.Add(item);
            db.SaveChanges();


        return Json(new { Resultado = item.Id }, 
           JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

minha View

```
   @using reCAPTCHA.MVC;


   <form id="submeter">
            <p id="divulgueSeuVideo">Divulgue Seu Vídeo</p><br />
            <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" required="" 
  class="form-control form-home" placeholder="Titulo" /><br />

            <input type="url" id="video-url" name="url" required="" class="form-control form-home" placeholder="url" /><br />

            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="minhaKey"></div>
            @Html.ValidationMessage("reCAPTCHA")

            <button id="submit" class="btn-block btn-success" onclick="funcaoOnclick();">Enviar Video</button>
        </form>
```

Ajax que faz a salva

```
   function SalvarItens() {

        var titulo = $("#titulo").val();
        var video_url = $("#video-url").val();
        var thumb = generateThumb(generateCode(video_url));
        var url = "/Home/SalvarItens";

        $.ajax({
            url: url
            , data: {
             titulo: titulo, video_url: video_url, thumb: thumb }
            , type: "POST"
            , datatype: "Json"
            , success: function (data) {
                if (data.Resultado > 0) {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Web.Config

```
  <add key="reCaptchaPublicKey" value="SiteKey" />
  <add key="reCaptchaPrivateKey" value="SecretKey" />
```

Comment: você pode validar na controller para verificar se está válido mesmo, dá uma olhada nesse exemplo: [reCaptcha](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/implement-google-recaptcha-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: Pelo que lembro, a validação do reCaptcha deveria ser feito no server, e para isso tua chamada ajax deveria estar enviando os "inputs" do reCaptcha além dos demais campos como título, video_url, etc.

Comment: mais como pego o valor do imput do reCaptcha?

Comment: no Json do seu post, você não deveria incluir o captchaValid também?

Answer (score 0):

Já que você precisa utilizar ajax ao invés do submit padrão do form, uma forma simples que vejo que fazer isso é assim:

```
var formData = $('#submeter').serializeArray()[0];
formData.Titulo = $("#titulo").val();
formData.UrlVideo = $("#video-url").val();
formData.Thumb = generateThumb(generateCode(formData.video_url));
var url = "/Home/SalvarItens";

$.ajax({
    url: url
    , data: formData
    , type: "POST"
    , datatype: "Json"
    , success: function(data) {
        if (data.Resultado > 0)
        {

        }
    }
});
```

Isso vai manter o hash gerado pelo reCaptcha quando ele é resolvido dentro do objeto `formData`. Com isso, o atributo `CaptchaValidator` na tua action deveria conseguir validar o reCaptcha e o parâmetro `captchaValid` deveria vir com o valor correto.

Na action, coloque esse código:

```
[HttpPost]
[CaptchaValidator(PrivateKey= "secretKey", ErrorMessage="Captcha 
Invalido", RequiredMessage ="Campo Obrigatorio")]
public ActionResult SalvarItens(Dados_Video item, bool captchaValid)
{
    db.Dados_Video.Add(item);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return Json(new { Resultado = item.Id }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```